# How would I vertically align JavaScript text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an alert box with text inside, but I can't think of any ways to move the text down within the alert box div, vertically centering it. I've tried line-height but that of course will not work for the two lines of text that I have when you view it on a browser with a min-width of 320px and max 480px. #alertmsg should remain at the top, however, the text within it should be centered when viewed on a mobile browser. I've also tried Vertical-align, but that doesnt work either. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I also tried to place a `<p>` in the JavaScript; no luck.

Here is my CSS:

```
#alertmsg {
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#252525;
    top:0px;
    padding-left:0px;
    width:100%;
    font-family:'gotham-medium', arial, sans-serif;
    src:url("http://www.3elementsreview.com/fonts/gotham-light.ttf");
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:1.2em;
    line-height:1.2em;
    text-align:center;
    height:63px;
    color:#ffffff;
    opacity:1;
    display:inline-block;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:1000;
    border-bottom:2px solid #ff6000;
}
```

And my JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (typeof window.sessionStorage != undefined) {
        if (!sessionStorage.getItem('mySessionVal')) {
            $('<div />', {
                id   : "alertmsg",
                text :"Join our email list and receive the latest updates at 3Elements Review.",
                on   : {
                    click: function() {
                        $(this).slideUp(200);
                    }
                }
            }).appendTo('body').fadeIn(1).delay(6000).fadeOut("slow");
            sessionStorage.setItem('mySessionVal', true);
            sessionStorage.setItem('storedWhen', (new Date()).getTime());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You can't align JavaScript strings, because strings have no format nor position.

Comment: @Marlon Fowler is this the problem you are experiencing http://jsfiddle.net/CRRRs/

Comment: if really touchy about it's vertical aligment... wrap it in span...get span height and adjust span posiiton accordingly when you insert the text

Comment: To clarify: are you talking about aligning the text within the div that you append, or aligning the div within the page?

Comment: @kozlovski5 That is how I want the text to behave, but instead media only screen it is flush at the top of the alert box. I would like it to be more in the middle for readability purposes.

Comment: @nnnnnn I would like to align the text within the div. That div (the alert box) should remain at the top of the page.

Comment: @Marlon Fowler are you wrapping the text in the p element like I have in the jsFiddle provided above?

Comment: @kozlovski5 I did wrap the text, but then the text disappears but the box stays.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
#alertmsg {
    position:absolute;
    top: 50%;
    height:63px;
    margin-top: -31.5px; /* half height */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/CRRRs/2/)